# react native expo exception

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm beginner in React, I followed instructions to create a new project and I can't run it in expo in my phone.
I made sure that my phone and my computer are connected in the same network and I m able to ping on each other.

I have this error: 
java.net.SocketTimeOutException: connect timed out.

Help ?

Answer (score 0):

I found why. It was interface of Virtual machine. Once disabled everythg works normally